# rqt_remocon not working

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error with InteractiveClientInterface given when trying to run rqt_remocon

```
:~/catkin_ws$ rqt_remocon
[debug] Interactive Client : initialised
[debug] Interactive Client : Connection Details
[debug] Interactive Client :   Node Name: rqt_remocon_5ac1cc7dba474fffbc40694462640841
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_MASTER_URI: http://192.168.1.103:11311
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_HOSTNAME: 192.168.1.101
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_MASTER_PORT: 11311
[debug] Interactive Client : Get interactions service Handle
[error] InteractiveClientInterface : failed to find all of the interactions' publications and services for [get_interactions]
^CPluginHandler.save_settings() plugin "rocon_remocon/Rqt Remocon#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 182, in save_settings
    self._save_settings(plugin_settings, instance_settings)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 109, in _save_settings
    self.emit_save_settings_completed()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 197, in emit_save_settings_completed
    callback(self._instance_id)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 426, in _close_application_save_callback
    self._close_application_shutdown_plugins()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 433, in _close_application_shutdown_plugins
    self._shutdown_plugin(info['instance_id'], self._close_application_shutdown_callback)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 321, in _shutdown_plugin
    handler.close_signal.disconnect(self.unload_plugin)
TypeError: disconnect() failed between 'close_signal' and 'unload_plugin'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236461/rqt_remocon-not-working/) by [Vpachalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27107/vpachalla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the error output it doesn't seem to be generic ROS issue, but instead application specific one. Maybe asking on the [package's forum](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_app_platform/issues) may get more attention esp. from the developers of the package (although asking on this answers forum is perfectly fine, many developers may not be paying attention).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0